# How do you find out if a word is present AS A WORD in a string?

Tags: php, string, tagging

Simply put, how do you find out if the 'the' is present in the following string:
'Well lately THEre seems to be much confusion between how to use THEy're, THEre, and THEir, I don't see what THE big deal is?'

The needle capitalized for exaggeration, just trying to figure out how to return the word the is found in the string, but if the string were filled with theres, they'res, and theirs, it wouldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a regex search for `/\bthe\b/`.

```
preg_match('/\bthe\b/', $text)
```

Comment: Don't forget about punctuation!

Comment: @Mark `\b` means "word boundary" and includes punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

search for ' the ' [extra space in the beginning and end]

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
/* if(stristr($haystack, 'the')){

   // do something

} */
```

*doh* didn't read the question closely enough.

Comment: "Well lately THEre seems to be much confusion between how to use THEy're, THEre, and THEir, I don't see what THE big deal is?"

Comment: Huh, I'm lost? stristr is case insensitive so it returns true in my example.

Comment: It also returns true if the string is "Well lately THEre seems to be much confusion." Which is what the OP specifically *didn't* want.

Comment: Agreed - didn't read the question closely enough - late Friday afternoon here :-)